# UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte X in position Y: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python, unicode

Estoy abriendo un archivo (csv) para lectura, pero durante la misma obtengo el siguiente error:

```
'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 328: character maps to <undefined>
...
  File "C:\Users\juan\source\repos\AsoVerde\AsoVerde\AsoVerde.py", line 10, in <module>
    for dato in rdatos:
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 328: character maps to <undefined>
The program 'python.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
```

Que se produce con el siguiente script:

```
import csv

filename = r"C:\datos\datos.csv"
adatos = open(filename)

rdatos = csv.reader(adatos)
for dato in rdatos:
    print(dato)
```

El error salta en la línea `for dato in rdatos`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El problema es que *python* está usando por defecto la codificación `cp1252` para *interpretar* el contenido del archivo, que evidentemente no está escrito en esa codificación, pues contiene un byte `0x81` que no existe en la misma.

Para procesarlo exitosamente, tyienes que averiguar la codificación en la que se encuentra el archivo que quieres procesar y abrirlo con el interprete adecuado para dicha codificación, por ejemplo:

```
adatos = open(filename, encoding="utf8")
```

Las codificaciones más comunes son `utf8`, `Latin-1`. Lo mejor es averiguar esto en la fuente de los datos, pero si esto resulta es imposible, como tip: Puedes abrir el archivo con Notepad++, ir al menú *Encoding* donde te dirá que codificación detecta en el archivo. Debes tener en cuenta que no hay un método 100% fiable para auto-detectar la codificación de un archivo que no tiene un BOM.